# Union Two Linq Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two LinqToSql queries that return result sets:

```
var grResults = (from g in ctx.GeneralRequests
                             join rt in ctx.RequestTypes on g.RequestTypeId equals rt.RequestTypeId
                             join sub in ctx.Logins on g.SubmitterStaffId equals sub.LoginId
                             join onb in ctx.Logins on g.OnBehalfOfStaffId equals onb.LoginId
                             where sub.GadId == gadId
                             select new
                             {
                                 Status = "Submitted",
                                 RequestId = g.GeneralRequestId,
                                 Submitter = sub.UserName,
                                 OnBehalf = (onb == null ? string.Empty : onb.UserName),
                                 RequestType = (rt == null ? string.Empty : rt.Description),
                                 ProjectName = (g == null ? string.Empty : g.ProjectName) ,
                                 Comments =  (g == null ? string.Empty :  g.Comments),
                                 LastUpdate = g.LastUpdateDate
                             });

  var grdResults = (from gd in ctx.GeneralRequestDrafts
                                  join rt in ctx.RequestTypes on gd.RequestTypeId equals rt.RequestTypeId
                                  into tempRequestTypes
                                  from rt1 in tempRequestTypes.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  join onb in ctx.Logins on gd.OnBehalfOfStaffId equals onb.LoginId
                                  into tempOnBehalf
                                  from onb1 in tempOnBehalf.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  join sub in ctx.Logins on gd.SubmitterStaffId equals sub.LoginId                                  
                                  where sub.GadId == gadId
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Status = "Draft",
                                      RequestId = gd.GeneralRequestDraftId,
                                      Submitter = sub.UserName,
                                      OnBehalf = (onb1 == null ? string.Empty : onb1.UserName),
                                      RequestType = (rt1 == null ? string.Empty : rt1.Description),
                                      ProjectName = (gd.ProjectName == null ? string.Empty : gd.ProjectName),
                                      Comments = (gd.Comments == null ? string.Empty : gd.Comments),
                                      LastUpdate = gd.LastUpdateDate
                                  });
```

The problem is when I try to Union them.

```
 var results = grResults.Union(grdResults).OrderByDescending(r => r.LastUpdate);
```

This returns no records even though the two individual queries do.

Comment: Check the result of `.ToList()` on the individual queries, and then on the Union result, to see what SQL is being generated.

Comment: I don't see why the Union would return no results.  That is very strange.  You could try `.Concat` if you don't mind duplicates. I would think it would be very difficult to get considering you are including LastUpdate which is probably is different between the records anyhow.  Concat would be quicker since it doesn't have to do a comparison to try and remove duplicates.

Comment: @David, please accept the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the 2 queries don't appear to rely on each other just execute both and union the results of each if you are just trying to get a single list.

```
var results = grResults.ToList().Union(grdResults.ToList())
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.LastUpdate);
```